# Adding covariates to a model with an outcome that has been normalized using the same variables

Tags: multiple-regression, linear-model, normalization, predictor, z-score

I'm interested in predicting cognitive scores (e.g. a memory test score) using multiple regression. The cognitive scores have been z-score normalized to age, sex, and years of education. Is it appropriate/necessary to include age, sex, and years of education as covariates in the multiple regression model, or can only the predictors of interest be included? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Such normalization is suspect.  It assumes constant variance and linearity, among other things (and normalization assumptions are almost never verified), and normalizing for a variable (e.g., age) may detract from the impact of the target variable.  For example it is common to have age-specific cutoffs of PSA for diagnosing prostate cancer.  PSA creeps up with age in normal men.  Age is the strongest risk factor for prostate cancer.  Normalizing PSA for age will detract from the diagnostic impact of PSA.

It is better to analyze raw data and to do direct adjustment using covariates, allowing for nonlinearities.

Comment: Hi Frank, thanks for your answer. I'm curious if your advice would change at all with a bit more information about one of the cognitive score distributions: one measure, called the MoCA (https://www.mocatest.org/), has a nearly discrete distribution with 12 unique values. When using the normalized scores, the distribution is more continuous (plot available here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/14B6huw4Ze1pJZuBFIQe4TLPCrQyuvDQ7/view?usp=sharing). Do you think it's still better to use the raw scores for this one?

Comment: I don't know of a normalization method that can turn a discrete distribution into a more continuous one, unless it involves randoming perturbing some of the raw measurements.

Comment: I have little experience with normalization so pardon my ignorance here, but as an example let's say you have 3 people with a raw score of 20. After adjusting for the covariates mentioned above their adjusted scores are, say, 18.8, 20.5, 21.2. Does this not yield a more continuous measurement? Here's a website where the adjusted MoCA score I'm referring to can be calculated: https://www.mocatest.ch/de/standardwerte/standardwerte-online-berechnen

Comment: Don't adjust raw scores for covariates to create a new score.  The score is the score.  Attempting to create an adjusted score changes its meaning.  In my example adjusting PSA for age will detract from both the age and PSA effects.